# Верно ли оборот с «благодаря» выделен запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

*В этот день они не торопились, потому что, **благодаря ровной дороге**, и так прошли больше, чем в предыдущие.*

Answer (score 1):

Я бы обособила обстоятельственный оборот с производным предлогом "благодаря":

*В этот день они не торопились, потому что, **благодаря ровной дороге**, и так прошли больше, чем в предыдущие.*

В общем случае обособление факультативное, но здесь оборот не совсем удачно вписывается в структуру предложения перед словом "и так".

Сравнить: *В этот день они не торопились, потому что **благодаря ровной дороге** прошли больше, чем в предыдущие* (нет обособления).

Answer (score 0):

Да, так как обособлять нужно слово "благодаря" + зависимое к нему.

То есть: благодаря (чему?) - ровной дороге.

Comment: Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «благодаря», **могут** обособляться: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_56 Здесь лучше без запятых.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YZ7zyiF.png